# Codeigniter: model foreach pass array to controller -> to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here is my model - I want to assign the rows and echo out on the view page e.g

**My Model:**

```
public function dsduan(){

       $data   =   array();
       $q = $this->db->query("SELECT duan.id, duan.tenduan, duan.diachi, quan.quan, duan.tdt, duan.mdxd, duan.tt, duan.cdt, duan.dvql, duan.dvtk, duan.dvtc, duan.dvgs, duan.loai, duan.tienich, duan.noidung, duan.hinhanh FROM duan LEFT JOIN quan ON duan.quan=quan.id ORDER BY duan.tenduan ASC");

        if ($q->num_rows == 1)
        { 
            foreach ($q->result() as $row)
            {                  
                $data[]['id'] = $row->id; 
                $data[]['tenduan'] = $row->tenduan;
                $data[]['diachi'] = $row->diachi;
                $data[]['quan'] = $row->quan;                   
            }
        }

        return $data; 
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function dsduan() {

     $this->load->model('madmin');
     $duan = $this->madmin->dsduan();
     $this->load->view('danhsachduan', $duan);        
}
```

**My View:**

```
<td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $tenduan; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $diachi; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $quan; ?></td>
```

**How do I properly pass my model array to my controller so that I can echo out on my view?**
My view Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: views/danhsachduan.php

Line Number: 44
```

Comment: post the restult of `print_r($duan);`

Comment: Add print_r($duan); to my controller. Result: Array ( )

Comment: Its not the way how a model function should be written. Kindly check my answer below.

Comment: `num_rows` will return `count` of resulted row, not `boolean` so, use `if ($q->num_rows > 0);`, And remember you are returning Array from model to controller so you can not print it directly as $id.

Comment: @ParagTyagi It was't for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you use two dimensional array:

> $data[]['id'] = $row->id;

then in your controller you pass this array to view.

so if you want to access two dimensional array into your view, you have to use foreach loop.

such as change your array in model like following:

> $data['id'][] = $row->id;

and in your view access array using:

```
foreach($id as $res)
{
   echo $res;
}
```

Comment: Result: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: views/danhsachduan.php

Line Number: 46

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/danhsachduan.php

Line Number: 46..

Comment: what is the result of print_r($duan) in controller?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [tenduan] => 1 [diachi] => 1 [quan] => Quáº­n 1 [tdt] => 1 [mdxd] => 1 [tt] => 1 [cdt] => 1 [dvql] => 1 [dvtk] => 1 [dvtc] => 1 [dvgs] => 1 [loai] => 1 [tienich] => 1 [noidung] =>
1

[hinhanh] => Logo -1.jpg )

Comment: ok..now try this line in your view: echo $id or echo $duan['id'] or print_r($id)

Answer (score 0):

Have **modified** your code. Kindly **replace** below with your code.

**Model:**

```
public function dsduan()
{
     $q = $this->db->query("SELECT duan.id, duan.tenduan, duan.diachi, quan.quan, duan.tdt, duan.mdxd, duan.tt, duan.cdt, duan.dvql, duan.dvtk, duan.dvtc, duan.dvgs, duan.loai, duan.tienich, duan.noidung, duan.hinhanh FROM duan LEFT JOIN quan ON duan.quan=quan.id ORDER BY duan.tenduan ASC");

     if($q->num_rows() > 0)
         return $q->result();
     return false;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function dsduan() 
{    
     $this->load->model('madmin');
     $data['duan'] = $this->madmin->dsduan();
     $this->load->view('danhsachduan', $data);        
}
```

**View**:

```
<?php foreach($duan as $d) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $d->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d->tenduan; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d->diachi; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d->quan; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have replace. This result my view:A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/danhsachduan.php

Line Number: 44

Comment: Hi, I have used library https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload. I don't know how store image name to my sql. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, it use `extract()` method when binding variable from controller to view. In this case, you can do like this.

In Model

```
public function dsduan()
{

       $data   =   array();
       $q = $this->db->query("SELECT duan.id, duan.tenduan, duan.diachi, quan.quan, duan.tdt, duan.mdxd, duan.tt, duan.cdt, duan.dvql, duan.dvtk, duan.dvtc, duan.dvgs, duan.loai, duan.tienich, duan.noidung, duan.hinhanh FROM duan LEFT JOIN quan ON duan.quan=quan.id ORDER BY duan.tenduan ASC");

       if ($q->num_rows)
       {
            $data = $q->result_array();
       }

        return $data; 
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function dsduan()
{
        $this->load->model('madmin');
        $data['duan'] = $this->madmin->dsduan();
        $this->load->view('danhsachduan', $data);

}
```

**In View**, if your array is multi-dimensional, you can use like this,

```
<?php foreach($duan as $d) { ?>
   <td><?php echo $d['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['tenduan']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['diachi']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['quan']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

if your array is one-dimensional, you can use like this,

```
   <td><?php echo $duan['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $duan['tenduan']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $duan['diachi']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $duan['quan']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your view like this

```
<?php foreach($duan as $d) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $d['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['tenduan']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['diachi']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $d['quan']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function dsduan(){

   $data   =   array();
   $q = $this->db->query("SELECT duan.id, duan.tenduan, duan.diachi, quan.quan, duan.tdt, duan.mdxd, duan.tt, duan.cdt, duan.dvql, duan.dvtk, duan.dvtc, duan.dvgs, duan.loai, duan.tienich, duan.noidung, duan.hinhanh FROM duan LEFT JOIN quan ON duan.quan=quan.id ORDER BY duan.tenduan ASC");

    if ($q->num_rows == 1)
    { 
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {                  
            $data['id'] = $row->id; 
            $data['tenduan'] = $row->tenduan;
            $data['diachi'] = $row->diachi;
            $data['quan'] = $row->quan;                   
        }
    }

    return $data; 
}
```